# IOS Standalone Web App Facebook Share Error 104

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook, share, fbdialogs

In one of my `Web App`, I have to integrated `Facebook Share` Feature. It is working fine for normal `Web APP`. Following is the code:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   name: "App Name",
   link: "App Links",
   description: "My Description",
   picture: "image",
   show_error: true,
   display: 'popup'
  },
  function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  }
);
```

It is properly sharing my content to `Facebook`, however in **iPhone**, when I select web app to **Add To Home Screen**, and then try to share link from the app added in home screen, it is giving error of `104`.

I have attached screenshot for reference

[image]

Any idea, how can I resolve this issue or if I am missing something?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to resolve this using URL Redirection as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1):

So here is my code.

I first determine if app is standalone or now and accordingly use the corresponding code

```
if(!standaloneApp) {
    FB.ui({
       method: 'feed',
       name: "App Name",
       link: "App Links",
       description: "My Description",
       picture: "image",
       show_error: true,
       display: 'popup'
      },
      function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
    );
} else {

   var fbShareOptions = {
      app_id: fbAppId,
      name: "App Name",
      link: "App Links",
      description: "My Description",
      picture: "image",
      display: 'popup'
   };

   window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?'+jQuery.param(fbShareOptions),'_blank');
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

- Thanks